Digital filter response at frequencies higher than the Nyquist frequency
In one system there is a maximum sampling limit of 500 Hz. And in the analog signal, there are waves with a frequency in the range up to 1600 Hz. With 500 Hz sampling, is it possible to remove frequencies higher than 200 Hz using a digital filter so that the aliasing does not occur?
Or is an analog low-pass filter necessary?
Thanks.

The aliasing occurs when the analog signal is sampled. Therefore, you need to make sure that the analog signal does not contain frequencies higher than Nyquist before sampling. In your case, the Nyquist frequency is $250 \, \texttt{Hz}$.
So you need an analog filter. The cut-off should be set lower than Nyquist, depending on how much aliasing your application can accept.
You can use a digital filter once the signal is sampled with whichever cut-off you want.
